# database error - how to fix?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have been getting this block of error

> Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
>                                                                                       Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.                                                                                       (near "tablenames_and_addresses": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: create tablenames_and_addresses (_id integer primary key autoincrement not null,name text not null,age text not null);)
>   at com.example.charisse.nd3a.DataManager$CustomSQLiteOpenHelper.onCreate(DataManager.java:42)

DATA MANAGER CODE

```
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String newTableQueryString = "create table"
                + TABLE_N_AND_A + " ("
                + TABLE_ROW_ID
                + " integer primary key autoincrement not null,"
                + TABLE_ROW_NAME
                + " text not null,"
                + TABLE_ROW_AGE
                + " text not null);";

        db.execSQL(newTableQueryString); //error points to this

}



   public DataManager(Context context) {
        CustomSQLiteOpenHelper helper = new CustomSQLiteOpenHelper(context);
        db = helper.getWritableDatabase(); //error
}
```

Main activity.java

```
    final DataManager dm = new DataManager(this);
```

//

```
  btnInsert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        dm.insert(etName.getText().toString(), etAge.getText().toString());
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,etName.getText().toString() + " has 
        been inserted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put a space after create table : `"create table "`

Comment: Hi! what about in this part?

Comment: You missed a white space after create table, so your Query is wrong, your have to add a white space, here is the good Query String : `String newTableQueryString = "create table "
                + TABLE_N_AND_A + " ("
                + TABLE_ROW_ID
                + " integer primary key autoincrement not null,"
                + TABLE_ROW_NAME
                + " text not null,"
                + TABLE_ROW_AGE
                + " text not null);";`

Comment: Thanks! i get it now that android is very sensitive when it comes to spaces

Answer (score 0):

Try dropping all your tables and restart them, make sure that leave the required spaces between words, SQL is very sensitive when it comes to spaces especially when creating tables. SQL is not case sensitive but differentiate your different table creation with small and capital letters.